# How to create a table with ONE existing row from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm frankly new to sql and this is a project I'm doing.

I would like to know if there's a way to connect one column in one table to another table *when* creating tables. I know of the `join` method to show results of, but I want to minimized my code as possible.

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, -->code I want connect with table match_record
    player_name CHARACTER
);

CREATE TABLE match_records (
    (id INT PRIMARY KEY /*FROM players*/),  --> the code I want it to be here
    winner INT,
    loser INT
);
```

Comment: you can reference the value in column from the other table column, but you probably mean smth else?..

Comment: @VaoTsun oh, how would you use the 'reference' keyword?? Is there video or guide I can also look up

Comment: please take a look at the code in my answer - there is example of how to use foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    id INT not null PRIMARY KEY, -->code I want connect with table match_record
    player_name CHARACTER
);

CREATE TABLE match_records (
    id INT not null PRIMARY KEY references players(id),  --> the code I want it to be here
    winner INT,
    loser INT
);
```

this way you restrict that `match_records.id` is only from `players.id`:

```
t=# insert into match_records select 1,1,0;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "match_records" violates foreign key constraint "match_records_id_fkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is not present in table "players".
> ```

So I add players:

```
t=# insert into players(id) values(1),(2);
INSERT 0 2
```

And now it allows insert:

```
t=# insert into match_records select 1,1,0;
INSERT 0 1
```

**update**
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING

> %#
>
> If the session user is a database superuser, then a #, otherwise a >.
>   (The expansion of this value might change during a database session as
>   the result of the command SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION.)

Comment: updated the answer to reflect your question. in short - just ignore those - they come with `psql` output when I copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT id,... from old_table where id = 1;
```